# Detecting namespace in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer

Is it possible to detect whether at a given point of code you are in a namespace?  In particular, I want to include a warning if a file is being including in the global namespace.

Comment: Can the file be included in only a particular namespace, or any namespace?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I'm including it in different namespaces to do some typedefs inside them and wanted a warning if the file was producing those typedefs in a global namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give you a hint that generates compilation error if header is not include in global namespace. If I know C++ constructiom which for sure generates compiler warning (other that #warning) then it could be used instead of compilation error.

Put in your header:

```
template <class A, class B>
struct AreSame { enum { VALUE = -1 }; };
template <class A>
struct AreSame<A,A> { enum { VALUE = 1 }; };

struct TestGlobalNamespace
{
   int test_namespace[AreSame<TestGlobalNamespace, ::TestGlobalNamespace>::VALUE];
};
```

When your header is include in some namespace you'll get an error.

Like in this example:

```
namespace Some {

struct TestGlobalNamespace
{
   int test_namespace[AreSame<TestGlobalNamespace, ::TestGlobalNamespace>::VALUE];
};

}
```

You'll get:

```
prog.cpp:17: error: size of array ‘test_namespace’ is negative
```

[UPDATE]

However the more probably would be this kind of errors:

```
prog.cpp:17: error: ‘::TestGlobalNamespace’ has not been declared
prog.cpp:17: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

Anyway - no one will dare to include your header to namespace other than global.

Comment: After I wrote this I realized you wanted opposite, warning when file is in global namespace. Then just do opposite. Create AreDifferent<A,B> template and you'll get opposite. Give me a note if you want this in such a way.

Comment: I realized that just added to my answer new set of errors is more likely. If you want your header to be included only in `Some` namespace - just use `Some::TestSomeNamespace`

Comment: This doesn't work for me... I need a static_assert<> that fires when NOT in global namespace. A compilation error won't do :/.

Comment: @CarloWood Did you try `static_assert(AreSame<TestGlobalNamespace, ::TestGlobalNamespace>::VALUE`== 1);` ?

Comment: @PiotrNycz If you try that in a random namespace then TestGlobalNamespace must be defined in that namespace (or it will say that they are the same of course). I managed to come up with a macro in the end that triggers an assert when used outside of global namespace, but deleted it in the end because I chose a different route.

Answer (score 2):

Good practice is including **all** headers in global namespace. Open all needed namespaces at the beginning of file and close them before end. Another way will inevitably lead to heap of problems.

** *Comment extension* **

To prevent unintended inclusion, you can do something like this:

```
In header:
#ifndef INTERNAL_INCLUDE
#error ...
#endif

When used:
#define INTERNAL_INCLUDE
#include "internal.h"
#undef INTERNAL_INCLUDE
```

Comment: Disagree. There are exceptions from this rule. For example in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp there is following include `// implicit conversion to "bool"
#include <boost/smart_ptr/detail/operator_bool.hpp>`

Comment: In my case, I'm using a file to declare some typedefs that I wanted confined to a namespace, and then including this file inside some different namespaces.  But, regardless of whether this is a good idea, it would be interesting to know the answer to my question. I'll mark my question language lawyer.

Comment: I see, boost developers used this in similar way. So, if you want to prevent header file from being unwittingly included, I wish you to add a preprocessor condition: `#ifndef _SOME_VAR_ #error bad include #endif`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the small inconvenience of requiring a second header, to be included in the global namespace before the first.

```
// stuff_guard.h - include from global namespace to guard stuff.h
#ifndef STUFF_GUARD_H
#define STUFF_GUARD_H
typedef char stuff_guard[1];
#endif

// stuff.h - must be included from non-global namespace, after stuff_guard.h
// No include guard - may be included multiple times, in different namespaces.

#ifndef STUFF_GUARD_H
#error stuff_guard.h must be included before stuff.h
#endif

typedef char stuff_guard[2];

static_assert(sizeof (stuff_guard) != sizeof (::stuff_guard), 
    "stuff.h must not be included from the global namespace");

// Put your stuff here
```

This will give reasonably friendly error messages if you break either of these two rules, and a somewhat less friendly error if you include `stuff_guard.h` from a non-global namespace.

If you're stuck with an old compiler and `static_assert` isn't available, then you could use `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`, or [roll your own](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6765770/204847).