# How can I force a compile error in C++?

Tags: c++, debugging, compilation, compiler-errors, output

I would like to create a compile-time error in my C++ code with a custom error message. I want to do this for a couple of reasons:

- to force compilation to fail while I'm working on new features which haven't been implemented yet. (compile time ! TODO reminder)
- to create a more readable error when attempting to implement an unsupported template specialization.

I'm sure there is a trick to doing this but I cant find a resource explaining the method. I would wrap the code in a #define of the form COMPILE_FAIL("error message");

Thanks
D

Comment: What you need is `static_assert`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765770/compile-time-assertion

Comment: static_assert totally does the job on msvc10... :-)

Answer (score 43):

Use `#error`:

```
#error "YOUR MESSAGE"
```

This produces an error from the preprocessor. If you want to detect an error at a later stage (e.g. during template processing), use `static_assert` (a C++11 feature).

Answer (score 26):

Look into [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert).

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class matrix {
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "Can only be integral type");
};

int main() {
    matrix<int*> v; //error: static assertion failed: Can only be integral type
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To force a compiler error (GCC, Clang style):

```
#error "You ain't finished this yet!"
```