# Detect one's or two's complement architecture in C++?

Tags: c++, architecture, c++11, twos-complement, ones-complement

What is the most reliable way to detect whether the architecture uses one's or two's complement representation in C++?

Comment: If those are the only options, check `(-1) & 1`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I work with heterogeneous supercomputer architectures and I want to record that at the beginning of each binary file to know whether it is compatible with the architecture that will try to read it.

Comment: doesn't little or big endianness matter much more today? And basically you are doing serialization, and there are libraries to do that reliably today..... [s11n](http://s11n.net/) and others

Comment: @Vincent - just compare "-1" with "~0".  They're *equal* with twos complement, they are *not equal* with ones complement.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You shouldn't have to worry - there aren't too many ones complement machines out there :)

But the easiest thing might be to compare "-1" with ~0.

Comment: Isn't that implementation-defined behaviour?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Of course it is. They'll be equal on a twos-complement implementation, and not on ones-complement (or sign-magnitude) implementations, and so can be used to test which representation is used.

Comment: Can you detect this with the pre-processor at compile time.

Comment: @LokiAstari `static_assert(-1==~0,"not 2's complement");`

Comment: there are many ways to simulate `static_assert` if it's not available https://stackoverflow.com/q/807244/995714 https://stackoverflow.com/q/6765770/995714

Comment: Or you can just compare -1 with ~0.  If they're not equal, you've got ones complement hardware.

Comment: What about sign magnitude representation?

Comment: @plasmacel on a sign-magnitude system ~0 is -INT_MAX which is also not -1

Comment: @MartinYork Assuming paulsm4's technique is sufficient, `#if ~0==-1` [also works](https://godbolt.org/z/hTTYKP1r4).  Of course in C++11+ a `static_assert` or `constexpr` variable is preferable.