# Is there a static_assert replacement which satisfies the C99 standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, c99, static-assert

I have been trying to implement a method similar to `static_assert` which is defined in the C++11 standard. The main problem is how does the C++ compiler write the text message being passed to `static_assert` as a `const char*`? I can get the compiler to write a message like `A_is_not_POD`. This is what I have:

```
#define MY_STATIC_ASSERT(condition, name)         \
   typedef char name[(condition) ? 1 : -1];
```

But it would be quite nice to get the compiler to write something like `"Error: A is not POD."` Any suggestions?

Comment: No that's not possible. The only thing you can get with older standards, is to spit out variable names.

Comment: “I can get the compiler to write a message like A_is_not_POD” How about showing what you have already done to achieve that? It would make your question clearer. The FAQ used to say “the best questions have a bit of source code in them” before it was re-revamped.

Comment: That's a shame. But where can we find the source code of static_assert  function? The interesting thing is how does the compiler write the string to the compiler message. I have been trying to use templates somehow but have been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: @Shubham C++11's `static_assert` is not a function - it's a keyword, just like `for`. There's no source code for `for` either. That's why the compiler can do anything it really wants with the arguments.

Comment: I would guess it's impossible, since Boost's static assert can't print messages in C++03. Presumably, they tried pretty hard to find a way; and if it's impossible in C++03, it's almost certainly impossible in C99.

Comment: There are certainly ways to get nice error messages in C99. The easiest is to use [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org) as your compiler. What compiler are you trying to get this to work on? (No portable solution exists, because the C Standard doesn't have any concept of "printing messages at compile time".)

Answer (score 6):

Not sure i understand question, but C11 have `_Static_assert(condition, errmessage)`. In C99 this functionality was missing but, depending on compiler, it could be possible to emulate. E.g. for gcc (unfortulately clang doesn't support attribute(error))

```
#define MY_STATIC_ASSERT(cnd, descr) ({ \
    extern int __attribute__ ((error("static assert failed: (" #cnd ") (" #descr ")"))) \
               compile_time_check(void); \
    ((cnd) ? 0 : compile_time_check()), 0; \
})
```

Comment: That's really nice. I didn't know we could do something like this!!! Its a shame clang doesn't provide this feature. Will however, will have a look around. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 3):

In the c99 standard there is no *"official"* way to perform a static assertion in your C++ compiler.

> "The main problem is how does the C++ compiler write the text message being passed to static_assert as a const char*?"

The C++ **compiler** detects an error in the code and prints out an appropriate error message based on a standard list of messages it has for each error that is known it can encounter. In c99, the compiler doesn't know what a "***static assert* error**" is, so you need to cause some ***other* error**.

However, because creating static asserts with a c99 compiler is kind of a hack, it is not capable of printing out a nice error message exactly how you want.

For your example,

```
#define MY_STATIC_ASSERT(condition, name)         \
    typedef char name[(condition) ? 1 : -1];
MY_STATIC_ASSERT(false, my_error_msg)
```

will trigger the `"error: size of array ‘my_error_msg’ is negative"` message in the **gcc** compiler (and should a similar message in other compilers, you hope!). Giving the array an error message for the `name` was a way to print out your own info. There are various other techniques/hacks you can do on purpose such as bad templates, enums [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765770/compile-time-assertion)

**Note:** you *can* provide custom compiler messages  prior to C++11 using **pre-processor** macros such as `#error` or `#pragma`. However **pre-process time** is not the same as **compile-time**! The the pre-processor has a limited ability to evaluate many expressions and keywords such as `"if"`, `"sizeof"`, `"return"` and so on have no meaning to the **pre-processor**, only the **compiler**. [link with some overview](http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-static-assertions.html)