# Local type as template argument inside not instantiated function

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, c++03, local-class

Local type as template argument is forbidden in C++03:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo { };

void Make()
{
  struct Unknown {};
  Foo<Unknown> foo; // Bad
}
```

Is there any directives in Standard about checking this rule in case of template **is not instantiated**?
Is it possible to be sure, that this rule is checked only after template instantiation attempt (no instantiation => compilation success)?

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo { };

template<typename T>
void Do(T&) { }

template<typename T>
void Do(T*) // usage with pointer is forbidden by-design
{
  struct Unknown {};
  Foo<Unknown>::UnknownMethod();
}

int main()
{
  std::string s;
  Do(s);
}
```

Comment: May be [`std::static_assert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) could help to do so.

Comment: It's not present in C++ 2003

Comment: Here's some code, how to implement such yourself with older c++ versions: https://github.com/makulik/StaticInterfaces

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How could `static_assert` help here?

Comment: @Constructor I thought of just putting it in the function body, that it would trigger a soon the function specialization is instantiated.

Comment: `Is there any directives about checking this rule` I don't know what you mean by this. Please clarify.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ As Jan Hudec explains in his answer "the rule does not say that instantiating template with local type as parameter in an error, it says using local type as template parameter is an error". `static_assert` can't help here at all.

Comment: @Constructor I more referred to the _'If you need to fail compilation when some combination ...'_ part.

Comment: @Constructor: As I also explain in my answer, `static_assert` _can_ help here. Because this is typical question of the form "How do I use X to do Y" where the answer is inevitably "use Z instead". Fortunately "Y" is mentioned, so we can say that static assert is the sought-for "Z".

Comment: @JanHudec Ah, I didn't notice his comment "usage with pointer is forbidden by-design". Then you and πάντα ῥεῖ are right, `static_assert` is appropriate here for Z part. I mean that it is not suitable for original X-Y.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm sorry, I didn't noticed that comment. Then you are right, of course.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: `static_assert` is not in the `std` namespace, it is a bit equivalent to `sizeof`, `alignof`, or `decltype` in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such directive in C++03, because

1. There are no directives in C++03 and
2. the rule does *not* say that *instantiating* template with local type as parameter in an error, it says *using* local type as template parameter is an error.

It is not supposed to be success if the template is not instantiated.

On the other hand, some compilers permit local types as template parameters (e.g. Visual C++; no, it does not follow standard, but that's life), so you can't use that to force compilation failure anyway.

If you need to fail compilation when some combination is attempted, use the standard static assert. You can use the [Boost.Static Assert](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html) implementation, the [implementation linked by πάντα ῥεῖ](http://github.com/makulik/StaticInterfaces) in comments or [the simple implementation in this other question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6765840/201725)<sup>1</sup>

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo { };

template<typename T>
void Do(T&) { }

template<typename T>
void Do(T*) // usage with pointer is forbidden by-design
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(false);
}
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>I am not sure whether it's correct though; I think that implementation may fail even if not instantiated unless the argument is argument-dependent in the enclosing template.</sub>

Comment: There's also support in the [Loki library](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/), which is a bit more lightweight than boost IMHO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I can't find any documentation for it there though.

Comment: Yeah Loki's documentation is poor (you should best have access to Alexandrescu's book).

Comment: Yes, it is well described in his *Modern C++ Design* book. His implementation of a static assert is described at the beginning of the second chapter as I remember.

Comment: Now I see that Z part is not so obvious. Static assert is still not necessary here. To disable `Do(T*)` overload one should simply not to implement it: `template<typename T> void Do(T*);`.

Comment: @Constructor: In C++11 this is the obvious choice (with `= delete`), however in C++03 this means a link-time error (or even, load-time error) instead of a compile-time error... and it might be non-trivial to understand where the method was called.