# Does the member function of class template not get instantiated if never be called?

Tags: c++, templates

I just started to understand some template basics. Actually, until now I just accepted it as a fact, but I dont really understand the reason why this is broken:

```
template <typename T,bool hasFoo>
struct Broken {
    void foobar(){
        if (hasFoo){T::foo();}
        else { std::cout << "BROKEN" << std::endl;}
    }
};

int main(){
    Broken<int,false> t;
    t.foobar();
}
```

while this works:

```
template <typename T>
struct Works {
    void foo(){T::foo();}
    void bar(){std::cout << "WORKS" << std::endl;}
};

int main(){
    Works<int> t;
    t.bar();
}
```

Somehow it is obvious, but I just want to make sure that I am not missing something:
Does this work, because if the function `Works<int>::foo()` is never called, it simply does not get instantiated?

PS: To avoid misunderstandings: I know, why `Broken` is broken and I recently had a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33465830/how-to-fix-this-template) related to this where I got good answers, however after that I thought that also `Works<int>` should not compile until I accidentally passed a "wrong" template parameter and was surprised that it did compile.

Comment: What error do you get? It's not just the spelling (`hasFoo` vs `hasFOO`), is it?

Comment: Have you done any attempts to solve this yourself? Have you read the error messages? There are a few.

Comment: @Axel see my PS. And thanks for pointing out the typo

Comment: @tobi303 I fixed that typo but you (presumably accidentally) edited over it.

Comment: @skyking sorry, I should have phrased the question in a better way. I hope my PS makes it more clear

Comment: @CompuChip yep ;) now its fixed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> if the function Works::foo() is never called, it simply does not get instantiated?

Yes, a non-virtual member function of class template won't be instantiated until it's required.

From the standard, [§12.8.1/10 Implicit instantiation [temp.inst]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#10):

(emphasis mine)

> An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function
>   template, a variable template, a member template, **a non-virtual
>   member function**, a member class, a static data member of a class
>   template, or a substatement of a constexpr if statement ([stmt.if]),
>   unless such instantiation is required.

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for. Maybe you can suggest a better title, because atm the question is pretty useless for anybody but me.

Comment: Good one... I couldn't really come up with anything shorter than "Invalid method is not instantiated in a templated class, but boolean template parameter in instantiated method fails at compile-time.".

Comment: " being used." is a poor phrase.   explicit instantiation doesn't "use" it by common meaning of the word (hence the standard saying "require instantiation" not "used")

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in your title, no, it does not need to be called to be instantiated.

This code does not compile, yet `foo` is never called.

```
template <typename T>
struct Works {
    void foo(){T::foo();}
    void bar(){}
};

// this requires foo being instantiated because it may be called from
// elsewhere - the compiler cannot know.
template Works<int>; 

int main(){
    Works<int> t;
    t.bar();
}
```

live: https://godbolt.org/g/u4frVZ

This is why the standard says it is not instantiated unless it *requires instantiation* and the rules for that are more complicated than whether it is called.