# Why is the C++ preprocessor not doing arithmetic properly on enum values?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, enums, c-preprocessor

The following code does NOT generate the `#error`, but instead compiles, runs, and output the trace value 37 (TT_LAST_PARM equals 53 and TT_FIRST_PARM equals 16):

```
#if ((TT_LAST_PARM - TT_FIRST_PARM) >= 32)
#error More than 32 parm tokens
#else
HTRACE("%d", TT_LAST_PARM - TT_FIRST_PARM);
#endif
```

If I hard code the values,

```
#if ((53 - 16) >= 32)
#error More than 32 parm tokens
#else
    HTRACE("%d", 53 - 16);
#endif
```

the pre-processor DOES generate the error:

Error   1   fatal error C1189: #error :  More than 32 parm tokens   d:\codeMTX\Knowbase\KBMatL\PrintParser.CPP  2663

Comment: You can't do this with the pre-processor - you need a compile-time assert.

Comment: The pre-processor does not know about enum names; to the preprocessor they are just undefined symbols

Comment: @antlersoft that makes sense - but I really don't like using #defines.  Why doesn't it flag as a PREPROCESSOR error, e.g. #if XYZZY?  I thought I would have to do #if defined(XYZZY) && XYZZY???

Comment: @PaulR I had the assert originally, but I try to flag errors at compile time when they can (should).

Comment: @franji1: yes, that's why I said you need a [compile-time assert](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6765770/253056) (i.e. not a run-time assert).

Comment: @PaulR awesome!  But I am using VS2008.  Stuck with the runtime assert.  But if/when I get there, I will DEFINITELY look into that!!

Comment: @franji1 There are ways to get a compile-time assertion in C++03. Boost.StaticAssert is one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`enum` is a C/C++ keyword, not a pre-processor directive.
Pre-processor directives are clearly denoted by a leading `#` symbol.

The pre-processor doesn't have/know a symbol called `TT_LAST_PARM` etc, and according to the C++ standard (§16.1 ¶4):

> After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined unary operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers and keywords, except for true and false, are replaced with the pp-number 0

So your expression evaluates to `(0 - 0) >= 32`

Comment: I would have hoped that `#if ( - ) >= 32` would have generated a preprocessor error  :-\

Comment: If you have C++11 you can test your enums with a static_assert.

Comment: agreed - but I am currently stuck w/VS2008.